# How can I turn .deb files back to .tar for reuse with other Linux distros?

Tags: decompilation, linux, development

We all know that Ubuntu is the most popular Linux distro today with plenty of application currently being developed for it. But then I use Fedora and some use other distros but still liked to have the same program from Ubuntu in their systems.

So how can I convert .deb files back to .tar so it can be recompiled for other distros?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with Reverse Engineering. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be the place you are looking for?

Also, so I'm at least being a helpful, a little converter called [Alien](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/) may be relevant to your interests if you are looking to convert .deb files. Or you can just extract them with "ar".

Comment: @Archenoth (and others) If you think the question is off-topic (I agree, by the way), please vote to close it! Click on the “close” button below the question, select “off-topic”, and “Vote to Close”. It's very important, especially during the private beta, that we indicate what we consider on-topic and off-topic.

Comment: This question is out of the scope of this website. As @Archenoth has previously noted. Clicking "close" button...

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this is an RE question. deb is a known format.

Also deb is a .ar it just has a specific internal structure you can decompress it with ar. or use undeb if you want to be fancy.

Here is a [howto for deb and rpm](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/01/28/how-to-extract-rpm-or-deb-packages/) just for reference

Also note that deb is usually a binary format and you can't really convert it to source.. unless of course it is a source deb! Any installation you do should probably be done into /opt and add the appropriate directories to your path so you don't pollute your installation with untracked binaries.